# titan delete vertex is not working properly

Tags: vertex, titan

I set up Titan with HBase.

I remove all vertex in the graph

It shows null after delete all.

```
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>0
```

But if I re-login titan, then there are bunch of empty vertex in the graph

```
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>85267
```

I check the value of one vertex, it is empty 
    gremlin> g.v(840012).map()

What is the reason for empty vertex? How can I clean them completely?

Comment: I've seen phantom vertices in cassandra (long since fixed), but hadn't heard of that behavior in hbase.  What version of Titan are you using? 0.3.2?

Comment: yes, i am using titan 0.3.2, hbase 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0

Comment: i tried g.V.remove(); g.commit(); then I got following error    13/09/19 00:51:24 ERROR consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLockTransaction: Lock expired: LockClaim [backer=com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLockStore@762f6f82, key=0x0-0-0-0-0-7-182-136, col=0x0-135, expectedValue=0x128-61-16-195] (txn=com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLockTransaction@21811d3)

Comment: do you have a HBase cluster or is there just one instance?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue in Titan with cassendra DB.

It was due to closing graph without committing.

```
g = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties');

// Delete Nodes 

g.commit();
```

execute "g.commit();"  before closing the graph.